# Create a JSON API in PHP Serving multipart/form-data File

Tags: json, rest, http, amazon-s3

I wanted to create a Streaming PHP API which sends out JSON files (and not a string).

**Here are the given:**

- We have an existing PHP REST API, which serves JSON data with `application/json` MIME type. However, the JSON data can sometimes go more than 6-10 MB, depending on the query.
- Another application will request from the endpoints of the PHP REST API but should receive a JSON file to automatically act as a multipart stream.

How should I construct my HTTP Headers, JSON content, etc. in PHP to serve the JSON as a file and not as a string to make it a streaming server?

Comment: to serve or to receive? why to use multipart when it's ONLY 10MB?

Comment: AWS API Gateway has a limit of receiving and sending 6-10MB payload. The JSON string can be larger.

Comment: encoding something as multipart is not going to change the payload size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have known earlier that I can use AWS S3 Select to automatically download batches of data, like CSVs or JSON, using event streams from BE to FE automatically instead of using Multipart/Form-data from BE to FE and use Blob and ReadableStreams to handle the incoming stream from the FE.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/introducing-support-for-amazon-s3-select-in-the-aws-sdk-for-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

I created a dummy server that serves `multipart/form-data`, and the Front End downloads the file as a string with `file.php` as the name of the file.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: multipart/form-data');
echo file_get_contents('file.json'); // 49 MB file
```

After collecting the `multipart/form-data` in the front-end, it should collect the JSON string as a stream and convert it to JSON object, like this:

```
const jsonData: string[] = []

// Stream and parse the data inside JSON
const stream = streamableResponse.nodeStream()

// Collect all json string
stream.on('data', (chunk) => {
  jsonData.push(chunk)
})

// Handle error of JSON stream
stream.on('error', (error) => {
  logger.error(`An error occured when getting the file contents for ${fileName}`)
  logger.error(error)
})

// Wait for the stream to finish
stream.on('end', async () => {
   const data = JSON.parse(jsonData)
   console.log(data) // Process object data
}
```

The code above will collect the HTTP response as a string first before converting it to a parsed JavaScript code.

Comment: This is definitely _wrong_ though. Multipart is a *different* way to encode data. If you tell clients its going to be `multipart/form-data`, but then return json you are basically lying.

Comment: Perhaps its fine for your use-case and works around some problem, but it's definitely not right.

Comment: @Evert Yes... it depends on the use case. Some do MULTIPLE pagination requests when collecting the data from the server. In this case, it only sends ONE HTTP request for download.

Comment: Still what you are doing makes no sense. This is not going to generate anything different, except you just set the wrong content-type header (which will probably break some clients). There's no difference if you set the content-type to `application/json`.

Comment: Just to very clear, if you were looking to use event streams, this snippet does nothing to accomplish this. The entire 49mb file will still get buffered into memory and sent all at once. Setting an (incorrect) content-type does not change how PHP behaves in any way.

Comment: True about the memory limitation... It solves the limitation of downloading 5-10 MB of data which an AWS API Gateway should tunnel. If you are concerned about "lying," there is an optional parameter called "isDownload" to make sure that it is only for download, and can be processed differently if "isDownload" is false.

Comment: Are you sure about that? It's still going to be 50MB, nothing has changed. Does AWS API Gateway ignore limits for certain content-types?

Comment: If you want to trigger a browser's download dialog, use the `Content-Disposition` header instead, but again i don't think this has any effect on potential response body limits.

Comment: Yes. You can only send around 6-10 MB of data within AWS API Gateway if the application is not `multipart/form-data` (as of now)

Comment: **edit** ok, very strange! This does make your application technically do something invalid, but if it works to circumvent AWS restrictions it works I guess!

Comment: Using `multipart/form-data` chunks the data automatically within only one request. The same `Content-Type` is used when you upload a file into a server. We are just executing it the other way around...

I do not think that using de facto standard of `multipart/form-data` does make it invalid, but I think the reason why you are hesitant is because we are conditioned to use `multipart/form-data` to be processed by the server and not by Front End.

Comment: No, I'm very familiar with the standards. It's perfectly fine to return `form-data`, but you are not returning `form-data`. All multipart responses use the same mime-envelope, and split different 'parts' using a boundary string. It's completely unrelated to chunking in PHP too. Chunking in PHP happens automatically if no `Content-Length` was set.

Comment: You should think of JSON and "multipart" as alternatives to each other. They are both a format for encoding data (with different features). With your PHP sample you are telling clients "I am about to send you a multipart/form-data formatted document" but then you send JSON instead. It's 100% invalid. I believe you if this is a hack to work around an AWS limitations. Sometimes you have to use hacks to get the job done, but what you're returning is not valid multipart, and it doesn't affect the chunked transfer-encoding (in PHP at least).

Comment: To see another example of multipart, check out the source of a HTML email. It's the same format! (and not JSON)

Comment: I encourage you to check what is the use case of `multipart/form-data` @Evert before you say it is an invalid usage because you can practically send any file using this `Content-Type` without the hassle of pagination. Feel free to let me know if there are other technologies beyond that. Give solution, please.

Comment: the point of multipart is so multiple objects can be packed in a single response, such as email attachments or file uploads. You can certainly pack a json file in a multipart, but you're not doing it correctly.  So you're not wrong about the use-case, you're encoding it wrong.  Take a look on for example wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages

Comment: But you're not trying to even pack multiple objects in one response, so it's hard to give you a recommendation on what to do, other than.. dont use that mimetype unless you actually use the correct encoding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239522/discussion-between-franz-noel-and-evert).